# $group aggregation results in BSONobj size error (must be less than 16mb)

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I have a very large dataset of persons which was imported in the following schema :

```
_id, personId, city, street, streetNo
```

Using this first stage of the query pipeline, I first group the address fields together :

```
{
    "_id": "$_id", 
    "personId": "$personId",
    "Address": {
        "city": "$city", 
        "street": "$street",
        "streetNo": "$streetNo"
    }
}
```

This first part completes instantly.

Now, the problem is that each person may have multiple addresses. I want to group the addresses together into one person by the personId :

```
{
  _id: "$personId",
  Addresses: {
    $addToSet: "$Address"
  }
}
```

I know that this query is valid and it works. But when I run the query, after a couple minutes I get the BSONobj too large error. Is it because a person has too many addresses making a document too large? Or is the dataset too large? 
How can I bypass this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please review the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/). Pay particular attention to the following:

> When returning a cursor or storing the results in a collection, each document in the result set is subject to the BSON Document Size limit, currently 16 megabytes; if any single document that exceeds the BSON Document Size limit, the command will produce an error.

As well as:

> Pipeline stages have a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. If a stage exceeds this limit, MongoDB will produce an error.

With this we can infer that with an error noting a 16MB limit, you're exceeding the document size limitation. Your assessment that a person has too many addresses is the correct one.

Unfortunately there's not much that can be recommended without knowing what your data looks like, or the full aggregation pipeline call. That being said, here is what I would do:

1. Try performing a grouping where instead of adding addresses to a set, you get a sum of the number of addresses associated with a person, e.g. `{$group: {_id: "$personId", total: {$sum: 1}}`.
2. Sort the documents by count so you can see which ones are the most problematic, e.g. `{$sort: {total: -1}}`.
3. Select one of the problematic ones and search for documents with the `personId` matching the document's `_id`.
4. Perform a normal count of all documents associated with that person, i.e. `db.your_collection.find({personId: ...}).count()` and compare this value to the count from your aggregation.
5. If these counts are similar (and especially if they're the same) take a closer look at the addresses associated with that person and try to see if you can find a cause for the `Addresses` set growing so large.
6. If at all possible, optimize based on your findings.